# How to emit event from one namespace to other namespace in serverside without user pass event to client site using SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I hope this question find you well as I'm new to Node.js and SocketIO?.

I have two namespace in server side adminNamespace and agensiNamespace

Below are event from adminNamespace that listen from client and want to pass new event to agensiNamespace

```
adminNamespace.on("connection", function (socket) {
    //admin assign to agency event
    socket.on("adminAssignToAgency", function (assignData) {
        agensiNamespace.emit("adminAssignUser", assignData);
    });
});
```

Below are the code in agensiNamespace that listen to event from adminNamespace

```
agensiNamespace.on("connection", function (socket) {
    adminNamespace.on("adminAssignUser", function (assignData) {
        console.log("Received event from admin and emitting to agensi:", assignData);
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do that if yes please give an example on step and explanation if you could.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `socket.on("adminAssignUser",...)`, not `adminNamespace.on("adminAssignUser",...)`?